# Where can I download chess games from a specific position into a PGN file?

Tags: opening, pgn, websites

Is there a website that will let me search for master-level games from a specific chess position and download them into a PGN file for free?

Answer (score 1):

Sure - I imagine there are quite a few.  Here's one:
https://www.365chess.com/

1. Expand Resources, and click on Board Editor
2. Clear the board,     and set up whatever position you want.  Make sure you state which side is to move, and whether castling is available still ...
3. Below the board copy the FEN of the position
4. Expand Search, and click on Game position
5. Choose whether to search in the Openings Explorer or Games Database
6. Click on Import FEN, and Paste in the FEN you copied from your position.  Click Load
7. Click on Search!

I think you have to create an account (it's free) to download PGNs, but many of the sites work similarly.

Comment: I believe that site only lets you download multiple games as a PGN if you pay. :/

Comment: Sorry :(  
I guess the reason I used to like 365chess is that they were cheap - it looks like the cheapest 'donation' they allow is now $15.

I've looked around a bit, and haven't found a great single place to do what I think you wish.

My understanding:
  - you are looking for  large database of 'good' games that you can search for a specific position
  - you wish to download the PGNs of all the games you find with that position

Can you say a little more?  Is this primarily for opening exploration, or middlegame positions, or some other wish?

Thanks - bob